# Identify a component controlling a resistor motor for NordicTrack E4.1

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components

Following the purchase of a second-hand NordicTrack E4.1 elliptical trainer, I noticed after a few hours of use that the resistance was no longer adjustable.

I think I have identified the failure: a component has visibly suffered.

[image: Component damage]
<sup>[Original](https://postimg.cc/KkHTjf9N)</sup>

I was able to find on the internet a user having a problem on a similar model and find the original marking: 6210 2083

[image: Original marking]
<sup>[Original](https://postimg.cc/HcyY0tY3)</sup>

For context, here is the image of the in-place component:

[image: In-place component]
<sup>[Original](https://postimg.cc/FdV9nHSJ)</sup>

We can see that it is completely exploded.

So I'm looking to replace it, but after spending my evening scouring forums, component sales sites and technical specifications, I am without success.

I suspect it is some sort of 6 V controller for the motor that sets the resistance, but I can't be sure.

What is this component, and what is it used for?

Comment: I think I found.
It must be a BD6210 motor controller
https://www.mouser.fr/c/?q=BD6210
It's ordered, we'll see
Edit post

Comment: What’s a resistor motor?

Comment: It's the motor that control the resistance against the user strengh to make the exercice more difficult